# What is sys/ioctl.h? Where/how can I add this for installing libtecla?

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to use libtecla with the bladeRF on Windows 10. However, after trying to make install, I am seeing the following error. I have not clue what is wrong. I see that it says there is no file or directory named sys/ioctl.h, but why is this? I am using MinGW for the GCC binary files of 5.3.0.

```
$ make install                                                                                                                                                                                  

make[1]: Entering directory `/c/libtecla/libtecla'                                                                                                                                              

gcc -c -O  -DPACKAGE_NAME="" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="" -
DPACKAGE_STRING="" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="" -DPACKAGE_URL="" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 
-DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DH
AVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -
DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1   -o 
normal_obj/getline.o ./getline.c                             
./getline.c:47:23: fatal error: sys/ioctl.h: No such file or directory                                                                                                                          

compilation terminated.                                                                                                                                                                         

make[1]: *** [normal_obj/getline.o] Error 1                                                                                                                                                     

make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/libtecla/libtecla'                                                                                                                                               

make: *** [normal] Error 2
```

Shouldn't this library have a reference to this library? If not, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: You'll need to install a POSIX compatibility layer [like cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). That or format your computer and install Linux or another POSIX-based Operating System.

Comment: I am trying to do this through cygwin, but it still doesn't work. What is ioctl.h? If i need POSIX compatibility, shouldn't this work through cygwin?

Comment: ioctrl provides device-specific low-level control of devices abstracted behind a file-based interface on a POSIX-based operating system. The MinGW port of GCC is going to attempt to compile a Windows executable, so the tool chain leaves out the bulk of the POSIX stuff because Windows just works differently. You will have to build for Cygwin using a different variant of GCC and hope cygwin can supply all the POSIX goodies you need.

Comment: I found an ioctl.h file, is there a specific location this needs to be in to can I simply add it to my path?

Comment: Unfortunately no. ioctrl.h provides information **about** functions and data structures that do not exist in Windows. Along with the header you need to have implementations of the functions that will perform as expected on Windows. Adding only the header is essentially lying to the compiler. You will be able to compile, but when the compiler hands the compiled objects off to the linker to actually put the program together, the build will fail.

Comment: I see, would activating the windows subsystem for Linux allow POSIX compatibility for this issue? I'm trying to avoid installing Linux on this machine, but if this POSIX issue is not able to be remedied through windows then I will probably have to pass everything off to a Linux based vm.